# WMIC equivalent to the PSEXEC -h switch

Tags: windows, batch-file, psexec, wmic

I have a batch file which contains a WMIC command to run another batch file on a Windows server.

```
WMIC /user:<myusername> /password:<mypassword> /node:<server> process call create "D:\mybatchfile.bat"
```

mybatchfile.bat launches an exe which requires certain parameters to run, which are present in this batch file. However, the exe launches and quits citing insufficient privileges to continue the operation. I have tried to launch WMIC with escalated privileges but I get the same error in the log files.

The same thing works with psexec with the following syntax:

```
psexec \\<server> -u <myusername> -p <mypassword> -h "D:\mybatchfile.bat"
```

which launches the exe fine, but we would prefer to run this using native commands. As I understand, the -h switch lets the program be run with the highest privileges.

Does anyone have an explanation of why this is happening? What would be the correct WMIC equivalent to the PSEXEC command that I have used?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried `WMIC /PRIVILEGES:ENABLE ....`?

Comment: Yes, I have, but unfortunately that gives the same error. I also tried the same command by using /env but to no avail
    `WMIC /user:<myusername> /password:<mypassword> /node:<server> /privileges:enable /env process call create "D:\mybatchfile.bat"`

Comment: Your command is wrong. `bat` files are not executable and this matters when execing properly. So `cmd /c "D:\mybatchfile.bat"`.

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR :

`powershell -Command "Start-Process cmd -Verb RunAs"`

### Details :

It sounds like the issue is the shell you're using (aka cmd.exe) doesn't have sufficient privileges.  Before a shell has acknowledged the UAC, the integrity level of the shell's process is "medium".  Activating an admin's elevated permissions effectively sets the integrity level to "high".  Which is exactly what `psexec -h` is doing.

While `cmd.exe` was never built to do this for itself, it can call out to other programs which can create processes with elevated integrity levels.  Examples include: `powershell.exe`, `wscript.exe`, and some COM objects.

### Validate Before :

You can verify this case by typing `whoami.exe /groups` at a command line. 
 The bottom line states what the current integrity level is, which is default "Medium Mandatory Level".  Success requires us to create a process with an integrity level set to "High Mandatory Level".  So now, we just need to pick one of the following options:

### Option 1 : Powershell

`powershell -Command "Start-Process cmd.exe -Verb RunAs"`

### Option 2: Batch Script

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "zFile=%temp%\sudo.tmp.vbs"

(
    echo Set objShell = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^)
    echo objShell.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "", "", "runas"
) > "!zFile!"

wscript /nologo "!zFile!" >nul 2>&1
erase "!zFile!" >nul 2>&1 || echo ;[e] Failed To Delete Temp File {"!zFile!"}
```

### Option 3: Command Line

```
echo Set objShell = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > %temp%\sudo.tmp.vbs
echo objShell.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "", "", "runas" >> %temp%\sudo.tmp.vbs
wscript /nologo %temp%\sudo.tmp.vbs
erase %temp%\sudo.tmp.vbs
```

## Validate After :

Same as before - type `whoami /groups` at a command prompt and you should now see the integrity level set at "high" (aka "SID=S-1-16-12288").